# WCF Service with basicHttpBinding and message security with algorithmSuite=Basic128Sha256Rsa15

Tags: wcf, security, service, message, basichttpbinding

I'm finding it very difficult to find an example on message level security for a WCF service. Specifically looking for an example on how to do message level security with basicHttpBinding and one of the following algoirthms: Basic128, Basic128Sha256, or BasicSha256Rsa15.

I have played a little in Visual Studio, but I missing a few things. I'm expecting to be able to setup the Web.Config so that th Wsdl states what security algorithms are required once published. Am I thinking about this wrong? Also how do I load the keys used on each end of the exchange.

I really just need a simple example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basicHttpBinding doesn't support message level security for solutions below .NET 3.0.

Comment: Hmm, ok, Maybe I got them mixed up. Maybe someone with edit privledges can correct the title. Still need an example though, that doesn't show the web.config or how to setup keys...

Comment: Message security is supported by basicHttpBinding since at least .NET 3.0. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

basicHttpBinding supports message level security via the [message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731338%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) element.
[SecurityAlgorithmSuite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.security.securityalgorithmsuite.aspx) provides a variety of algorithms for use in this context. There is a reasonably good example available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751503%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in the MS docs.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx Check this link . It says basicHttpBinding support the  Message level.